# Calling a random SKAction when my score increments?

Tags: ios, swift, random, skaction

I have three SKAction variables, all of them change the color of my ball on the screen. I want to make it so that whenever my score increments, it selects a random action out of the three. Is this possible? It would mean so much if you could help me. Thanks.

Here is my code thus far:

```
let colorize1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

let colorize2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

let colorize3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

if score == 0 {
        Ball.runAction(colorize1)

    }
```

I have a for loop incrementing my score everytime "this thing" happens. When my score increments by 1 I want the ball to do colorize1, colorize2, or colorize3.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps putting the 3 SKActions in an array and then randomly picking an index between 0 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

```
let colorize1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

let colorize2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

let colorize3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.001)

let actions = [colorize1, colorize2, colorize3]

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

let action = actions[randomIndex]

let b = Ball()
b.runAction(action)
```

Comment: Though I would go one step further and say that you probably want to establish the 3 actions in an instance variable so you aren't creating the 3 actions each time the score increments.